# Meta Tags Module: Set of available meta tags is different for certain node types

Tags: 9, meta-tags

I have a behaviour, which I don't understand: using Meta Tags and a couple of sub modules (like twitter cards, schema.org: JobPosting, etc.) On `/admin/config/search/metatag/add` I see them for certain node types and for others not. Does anybody know why this is and how to fix it?

Expected for all content types:

[image]

Not Expected, I just switched the type and everything under twitter-cards vanishes:

[image]

The node type config has no structural difference I can detect, so I guess it must be something else.

Comment: I also opened a Support Request Ticket with the module maintainers themself: https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag/issues/3244874

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the metatag settings at `/admin/config/search/metatag/settings` for each type.

Note the description on the settings page:

> Identify which metatag groups should be available on which entity type
> / bundle combination. Unselected groups will not appear on the
> configuration form for that entity type, reducing the size of the form
> and increasing performance. If no groups are selected for a type, all
> groups will appear.

It's possible that someone selected some of the metatag groups for certain node types, **which will cause the other types to be hidden**.

This is one of those annoying Drupal forms where the rule is:

- If you select some items, they will be selected.
- If you select no items, all items are selected.

Comment: Thx man! I knew I was overlooking something "very obvious" :)

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer, Patrick.